# I want to capture scenarios based on slicers selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to capture the data that i get on the basis of selection from slicers with the details of slicer values selected

I was able to copy the data but not the slicer values

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set xSheet = ActiveSheet
        If xSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
            xSheet.Range("A1:B5").Copy
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Getting the slicer values along with the data

Comment: *I was able to copy the data but not the slicer values* - what have you tried (see [mcve]) to get the slicer values? I don't see any code related to that.

Comment: ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Slicer_CLIENT_ALIAS")).Select
Selection.Copy
ws.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: 1) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55851547/edit) your question with the code, not in a comment. 2) try looping them the items int he slicer and checking which ones are selected.